# ios UISplitViewController issue

Tags: ios, orientation, uisplitviewcontroller, uipopovercontroller, uisplitviewdelegate

I have an application that uses a `UISplitViewController`. I am adding it's delegate and assigning a button on the navigation bar for when the app is in portrait mode, to be able to show the master view controller in a popover view :

```
/*

   @property (strong, nonatomic) id detailItem;
   @property (strong, nonatomic) UIPopoverController *masterPopoverController;

   */
    #pragma mark - Managing the detail item

    - (void)setDetailItem:(id)newDetailItem
    {
        if (_detailItem != newDetailItem) {
            _detailItem = newDetailItem;
            // do smth
        }

        if (self.masterPopoverController != nil) {
            [self.masterPopoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
        }
    }

    #pragma mark - UISplitViewDelegate methods

    - (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)splitController willHideViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController withBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem forPopoverController:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController
    {

        barButtonItem.title = NSLocalizedString(@"", @"");
        UIImage *imag = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"gray_button"]resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 7, 0, 7)];
        UIImage *imag_pressed = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"gray_button_pressed"]resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 7, 0, 7)];
        UIImage *more = [UIImage imageNamed:@"shows_button_pressed.png"];

        [barButtonItem setBackgroundImage:imag forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
        [barButtonItem setBackgroundImage:imag_pressed forState:UIControlStateHighlighted barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
        [barButtonItem setImage:more];
        [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:barButtonItem animated:YES];
        self.masterPopoverController = popoverController;
    }

    - (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)splitController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController invalidatingBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem
    {
        // Called when the view is shown again in the split view, invalidating the button and popover controller.
        [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:nil animated:YES];
        self.masterPopoverController = nil;

    }
```

If an option is chosen in the master view controller, the RootViewController( which is basically the detail split of my split view controller ) will change with a replace-type segue. Once again I am assigning the `UISplitViewController` delegate.
My issue is, the bar button doesn't show after the root has been changed unless I put the device in landscape mode and then go back to portrait. If I do so, the button is there and does it's job.

How could I make the button appear without putting the device on landscape and then going back to portrait?

PS: I've tried both assigning the new delegate in `prepareForSegue:` method in the old root view controller and assigning the new delegate in `viewWillAppear:` method in the new root view controller. The same thing happens. 
Another thing : the new root view controller implements the `<UISplitViewControllerDelegate>`

UPDATE :

I found that the method : `- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc willHideViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController withBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem forPopoverController:(UIPopoverController *)pc` gets called only after I go from landscape to portrait so that is why I need to rotate the device in order to get the button to show.

The difference between the two delegates is that the first one is added in my `AppDelegate.m` and the second one in the `prepareForSegue:` method, in the old root view controller. The above method gets called for the old root view controller as soon as the app launches.